# Yii2 How to access model or session in web/css/custom.php folder file

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

In Yii2 i try add dynamic css loading.So i add php file in web/css/custom.php.Now i cannot access model or session in custom.php. It showing some error.

Now i adding session concept but showing this error `Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found`.layout file i mentioned custom file link.`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/web/css/custom.php">
$sessionArray = Yii::$app->session['settings'];`

Please any one can help.how to solve this issues.

Comment: import Yii package in your custom.php file

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest a different approach:

1. create a raw layout file
2. create a custom action
3. put your code in a view file

/views/layouts/raw.php

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?= $content ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php

```
<?php
    public function actionCustomCss()
    {
        $this->layout = "raw";
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/css');

        return $this->render('css');
    }
?>
```

/frontend/views/site/css.php

```
html, body {
font-family: <?= implode(['Consolas', 'Arial'], ', ') ?> !important;
    color: <?= "red "?> !important;
}
```

and use it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/custom-css']) ?>">
```

---

now, in your view file you can use Yii::$app and so on.